# Point-free version of g(f(x)(y))

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree, combinators

Is there a way to express the following in point-free form:

```
g(f(x)(y))
```

It is not a common 'combinator' as far as I can see, though there are perhaps different ways to express it?
I am working in Javascript with Ramda.

Comment: This is the somewhat well-known [*Blackbird* combinator](https://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/combinator/birds.html), `λabcd . a(bcd)`.  The answer from Ori Drori gives a simple version and the comments on it from customcommander gives a nice alternative.

Comment: Trivia: the bluebird in Haskell is `.`, which you have to enclose in parenthesis if you want to pass to other functions as an argument, `(.)`; the blackbird in Haskell is therefore `(.).(.)`, which sometimes called the _tits operator_, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a readable way to create this combinator in a point-free form. However, since the introduction of arrow functions to JS it's pretty easy to create readable combinators. You can also curry them using Ramda's `R.curry`, instead of manually curry them (`f => g => x => y => g(f(x)(y))`):

```js
const { curry, on, identity, multiply, add } = R

const combinator = curry((f, g, x, y) => g(f(x)(y)))

const square = n => n * n;

const squareAddition = combinator(add, square)

const result = squareAddition(1, 2)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: If you're using Ramda it feels like just `pipe(f, g)` would do?

Comment: `pipe(f, g)` is equivalent of the result of calling `combinator(f, g)`, and not a combinator by itself, and it's not curried.

Comment: Ah okay. `const C = curryN(2, compose(curry, pipe)); C(add)(negate)(40)(2);` ?

Comment: Very nice, but readability suffers. Post this as an answer. It's exactly what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Agreed. I prefer your version anyway ;) was just confused initially and keep forgetting about pipe not currying the resulting function

Comment: Thanks. You actually got something pretty simple, and the `compose(curry, pipe)` is pretty slick. My ideas included converting the params to any array with R.unapply, and then picking the arguments one by one to combine them, which were super un-readable.

Comment: This is great, both the answer and the alternative from @customcommander.  But I would prefer a different example, as `add` and `negate` commute with one another so the example doesn't make it clear whether this is `add (negate (x)) (negate (y))` or `negate (add (x) (y))`.  Perhaps `combinator (add, square)` would do?

Comment: Good idea. Updated to square.

Comment: Nice answer and discussion!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a point-free `comp2` -

```js
// comp : ('b -> 'result) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'result)
const comp = f => g =>
  x => f(g(x))

// comp2 : ('c -> 'result) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'result)
const comp2 =
  comp(comp)(comp)

// square : number -> number
const square = x =>
  x * x

// add : number -> number -> number
const add = x => y =>
  x + y
 
// addThenSquare : number -> number -> number 
const addThenSquare =
  comp2(square)(add)
  
console.log(addThenSquare(3)(2))
// 25 : number
```

Sure it's point-free and it works, but maybe this `comp2` is more suitable for you -

```js
// comp2 : ('c -> 'd) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'd)
const comp2 = f => g =>
  a => b => f(g(a)(b))
```

Here are `comp3`, `comp4`, and `comp5` if you think you need them -

```js
// comp3 : ('d -> 'result) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'result)
const comp3 =
  comp(comp)(comp2)

// comp4 : ('e -> 'result) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'result)
const comp4 =
  comp(comp)(comp3)

// comp5 : ('f -> 'result) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e -> 'f) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e -> 'result)
const comp5 =
  comp(comp)(comp4)
```

Comment: Considering that the OP asked how to express `g(f(x,y))` _in point-free form_, I think this answer is more correct, because at least it builds the _blackbird_ combinator (as noted in a comment to the question, this is the name of the combinator the OP describes) starting from a more fundamental combinator, the _bluebird_, that @Mulan calls `comp`, because it's the function composition bird.

Comment: This reminds me of the good ol' `comp(comp) (comp)`. Boy was I excited when a learned about it. Isn't the symmetry just comforting?